# Pglogical - multiple database tables to single table

Tags: postgresql, replication, pg-logical

I have 4 databases, each database is having 2 tables. The table structure on all the databases are same. So i want to replicate these two tables from all 4 databases to a single database.

So my centralized db will have 2 tables. Those tables having all 4 databases data.

FDW would be a better solution. But  i have logical replication as the required solution. So want to know the approach, possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, Its possible, I have tested with this. But we have to make sure that if you have any PK, Unique key it should unique across your source databases(all 4).Or on the subscription database create the table without the constraints.